# ANTLR ActionScript to Java issue

Tags: antlr

Really hope somebody can help with this.  I have been playing around with Robert Stehwien's ANTLR script to creating ASTs for excel like formulas.

http://arcanecoder.blogspot.co.uk/2008/04/using-antlr-to-create-excel-like.html

While it looks like the generated code is fine when running as ActionScript, when I port over to Java, I find a funny little issue.

The following Formula has a tree of "+" rather than "(+ 1 2)".  This is the simplest case I could find, however other formulas also fail to create the correct tree.

> (1 + 2)

However, the following works fine:

> 1 + 2

Any ideas what could be causing this?  Many thanks in advance!!

Apologies for the code dump below, I am not sure how else I can simply explain the issue.  Here is the code I am using to pull out the tree string:

```
ANTLRStringStream input = new ANTLRStringStream("(1 + 2)");

FormulaLexer lexer = new FormulaLexer(input);
CommonTokenStream tokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
FormulaParser parser = new FormulaParser(tokenStream);

ParserRuleReturnScope scope = parser.formula();
CommonTree expressionTree = (CommonTree) scope.getTree();

System.out.println(expressionTree.toStringTree());
```

And here is the final ANTLR script.  This is almost identical to the original, with the ActionScript option removed:

```
/*
Originally written by Robert Stehwien
*/

grammar Formula;

options {
    output=AST;
    ASTLabelType=CommonTree;
}

tokens {
    POS;
    NEG;
    CALL;
}


@package {com.arcanearcade.antlr}
@lexer::package {com.arcanearcade.antlr}

formula
    : (EQ!)? expression
    ;

//The highest precedence expression is the most deeply nested
//Precedence ties are parsed left to right
//Expression starts with the lowest precedece rule
expression      
    : boolExpr
    ;
boolExpr
    : concatExpr ((AND | OR | LT | LTEQ | GT | GTEQ | EQ | NOTEQ)^ concatExpr)*
    ;
concatExpr
    : sumExpr (CONCAT^ sumExpr)*
    ;
sumExpr
    : productExpr ((SUB | ADD)^ productExpr)*
    ;
productExpr
    : expExpr ((DIV | MULT)^ expExpr)*
    ;
expExpr
    : unaryOperation (EXP^ unaryOperation)*
    ;
unaryOperation
    : NOT^ operand
    | ADD o=operand -> ^(POS $o)
    | SUB o=operand -> ^(NEG $o)
    | operand
    ;
// the highest precedence rule uses operand
operand
    : literal 
    | functionExpr -> ^(CALL functionExpr)
    | percent
    | VARIABLE
    | LPAREN expression RPAREN -> ^(expression)
    ;
functionExpr
    : FUNCNAME LPAREN! (expression (COMMA! expression)*)? RPAREN!
    ;
literal
    : NUMBER 
    | STRING 
    | TRUE
    | FALSE
    ;
percent
    : NUMBER PERCENT^
    ;

STRING
    :
    '\"'
        ( options {greedy=false;}
        : ESCAPE_SEQUENCE
        | ~'\\'
        )*
    '\"'
    ;
WHITESPACE
    : (' ' | '\n' | '\t' | '\r')+ {skip();};
TRUE
    : ('t'|'T')('r'|'R')('u'|'U')('e'|'E')
    ;
FALSE
    : ('f'|'F')('a'|'A')('l'|'L')('s'|'S')('e'|'E')
    ;

NOTEQ           : '<>';
LTEQ            : '<=';
GTEQ            : '>=';
AND             : '&&';
OR              : '||';
NOT             : '!';
EQ              : '=';
LT              : '<';
GT              : '>';

EXP             : '^';
MULT            : '*';
DIV             : '/';
ADD             : '+';
SUB             : '-';

CONCAT          : '&';

LPAREN          : '(';
RPAREN          : ')';
COMMA           : ',';
PERCENT         : '%';

VARIABLE
    : '[' ~('[' | ']')+ ']'
    ;
FUNCNAME
    : (LETTER)+
    ;
NUMBER
    : (DIGIT)+ ('.' (DIGIT)+)?
    ;

fragment
LETTER 
    : ('a'..'z') | ('A'..'Z')
    ;
fragment
DIGIT
    : ('0'..'9')
    ;
fragment
ESCAPE_SEQUENCE
    : '\\' 't'
    | '\\' 'n'
    | '\\' '\"'
    | '\\' '\''
    | '\\' '\\'
    ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always make sure that the root of any AST is a single (unique) token (not a parser rule), and in case of rewriting a single parser rule, don't do `... -> ^(single_parser_rule)` but simply do: `... -> single_parser_rule`

So in your case, in the `operand` rule, change `-> ^(expression)` to `-> expression`:

```
operand
    : literal 
    | functionExpr -> ^(CALL functionExpr)
    | percent
    | VARIABLE
    | LPAREN expression RPAREN -> expression
    ;
```